# Адаптивное изображение при фиксированной высоте

Tags: html5, css3

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста - у меня есть изображение с шириной 2560px и с высотой 660px. Необходимо чтобы такая высота была фиксированной на любом разрешении, но как при таком условии можно сделать картинку адаптивной?
И возможно ли?[image: example img]

Comment: может вам подойдет background-size:cover https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/n5qfa/

Comment: Возможно с применением бутстрапа.